# Using select.kqueue() to tell when file is modified in python?

Tags: script, python

How can I use `select.kqueue()` to find out when a file in a folder has been modified?

Comment: stackoverflow ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this: https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog that seems to be working like a charm!